# Opacity of text/div issue with Internet Explorer 8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I've this website  [www.easyslide.it/prodotti/kit-easy-slide/](http://www.easyslide.it/prodotti/kit-easy-slide/) where, as you can see, text (or some other elements) seems to change its opacity.

Also there's a transparent space instead of an image on left side of the tab.

Obviously I'm facing these problems using Internet Explorer 8.

This problem is quite weird because I can reproduce this issue only on XP PCs. With emulators (IE Tester, IE Tab on Chrome, IE11 compatibility mode enabled) I can't reproduce the problem.

Any suggestion?

I attach a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: What's not working? That screenshot seems to have opacity in it, doesn't it?

Comment: Hi Joey! Have a look to the text. It's transparent on right side and show the background.

Comment: Oh, you mean those strikes going through the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `-ms-filter`?

See - http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-opacity/

Comment: Yep, done! But setting the right opacity for the background, then text disappear